# Python: Embed Audio (e.g., MP3, WAV) into a PDF

Tags: python, pdf, audio

You read that correct, I would like to programatically embed audio files into a PDF. The idea is that when a user opens the PDF, they can press a button within the PDF to play an embedded stream. It would be nice if they could fast-forward, rewind, but that is not fully necessary.

I know it is possible add audio to PDFs using Adobe tools, but I not aware how to do that with Python. A command line tool that is callable from python would also work.

Comment: did you get this working?